# Is there any way to ARP ping on Windows?

Tags: windows, ping, arp

On Linux and other systems, there is an utility called arping which can be used to send ARP requests ("pings") and show the answers, much like the "ping" utility but using ARP instead of ICMP.

Is there any way to do the same on Windows? (I use Windows 7)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Arping for windows does actually exist.

http://freshmeat.net/projects/arping/

Correction: this is for Linux, MAC OSX, etc... but can be installed on windows through cygwin.

Comment: To be clear, anything on the network nowadays needs to respond to ARP, therefore just about anything "supports" ARP pinging. Whether or not they have a nice packaged-with-a-bow utility for doing so is the question.

Answer (score 16):

If you clear Window's arp cache ( arp -d ) and then try to ping the ip address, it will issue a arp broadcast.

Check it out with Wireshark.

Comment: Is this behavior guaranteed?

Comment: @Pacerier: Yes, since ICMP (ping) is built on top of the IP layer. The IP layer needs the hardware address for a given IP address in order to know who to send its packet to. If the ARP cache is empty, the IP layer will have no choice but to issue an ARP request before it can send the packet.

Comment: This behavior is *NOT* guaranteed. It will only happen if the IP address is reachable according to subnet rules; otherwise it will use the IP address of the default gateway to issue an ARP request.

Answer (score 9):

A built in way to do this in windows:

```
cmd /V /C "set "IP=10.0.2.2" & FOR /L %i in () do @ping -n 1 -w 1000 "!IP!" >NUL & arp -a | findstr /c:"!IP! "
```

If you want to show a fresh ARP result each time (Needs to run as administrator)

```
cmd /V /C "set "IP=10.0.2.2" & FOR /L %i in () do @arp -d & @ping -n 1 -w 1000 "!IP!" >NUL & arp -a | findstr /c:"!IP! "
```

Comment: Wow, this is hardcore -- I love i!  And it's almost working here.

Actually I had to add a space between `-n` and `1` so it became:
`... @ping -n 1 ...`

Comment: This loop runs for ever. I think what you intended is `cmd /V /C "set "IP=10.0.2.2" & FOR /L %i in (1,1,2) do @ping -n 1 -w 1000 "!IP!" >NUL & arp -a | findstr /c:"!IP! "` which runs twice and so picks up duplicate MAC addresses.

Comment: Could you explain what this command is doing?

Comment: @RaisingAgent

Sure, as we are using a variable within the command, we use a variable expanded command prompt (/v) that runs once (/c).

Then sets an IP address to your target ip

Then creates an endless loop, that will ping and then ARP resolve a target

Comment: `-w 0` works just as well,  there's no need to wait for the ping to return at all. Much faster if you're adapting this to run in a loop for multiple IPs

Answer (score 6):

WinXP's ARP command is for displaying data only.  Try Nmap, it's free and fairly easy for this type of scan.  Nmap is available at insecure.org.

Comment: That's probably the closest I can get to the arping utility (using nmap -PR -sP <host>). Congratulations, you won.

Comment: @e-t172 With newer versions of nmap, the command `nmap -PR -sn <host>` is preferred. `-sP` is deprecated. Also, this only worked for me when I ran it as root.

Answer (score 6):

## Try "arp-ping.exe"

Thought I would add this tool which runs directly from the command prompt:

- Eli Fulkerson, [*arp-ping.exe - an implementation of ping via arp lookup*](http://www.elifulkerson.com/projects/arp-ping.php) (Archived [here](https://archive.is/jOEZR).)

**arp-ping.exe command line options**

```
Usage: arp-ping.exe [options] target
        -s ip : specify source ip
        -n X  : ping X times
        -t    : ping until stopped with CTRL-C
        -x    : exit immediately after successful ping
        -i X  : ping every X seconds
        -d    : do an 'arp -d *' between pings (requires Administrator)
                (-d prevents cached ARP responses on Windows XP.)
        -c    : include date and time on each line
        -m X  : ignore failures that take less than X milliseconds
        -.      : print a dot (.) for every ignored failure
        -l    : print debug log
        -v    : print version and exit
```

**Versus the Linux "arping" command line options**

```
Usage: arping [-fqbDUAV] [-c count] [-w timeout] [-I device] [-s source] destination
-f : quit on first reply
-q : be quiet
-b : keep broadcasting, don't go unicast
-D : duplicate address detection mode
-U : Unsolicited ARP mode, update your neighbours
-A : ARP answer mode, update your neighbours
-V : print version and exit
-c count : how many packets to send
-w timeout : how long to wait for a reply
-I device : which ethernet device to use (eth0)
-s source : source ip address
destination : ask for what ip address
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check this out: https://github.com/seladb/PcapPlusPlus/tree/master/Examples/Arping. This is a cross-platform Arping that can work both on Windows, Linux and Mac OS X

Answer (score 2):

This is not exactly an ARP "ping" but running "arp inet_addr (ip address)" from a command prompt will send a single ARP request to the host specified in (ip address). You can then run "arp -a" to see the result.

Comment: Just doesn't work. I get my prompt back but nothing happened. A sniffer didn't show any ARP requests coming out. Same result if the IP address is not already in the ARP table.

Comment: Right, you don't get a result back. The command sends a single ARP request to the ip address, which you can then see the result by issuing the arp -a command. I said it's not exactly an arp ping, but it does send a single arp request.

Comment: No it doesn't. As I said, a network sniffer doesn't show any ARP request going out, and no entry is added to arp -a.

Comment: That's strange. It works exactly as I described on Windows 7 but not on Windows XP. Sorry.

Comment: Doesn't work for me either on Win7, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can arp-ping with [CAIN](http://www.oxid.it/cain.html), which is free.

Answer (score 1):

Hardping is a decent program that does this.

There's the full version that costs money that's more of a ping sweep program, but I just use the freeware version.  The free one only does 1 ip at a time, but that's all I needed it for.

You'd use it like 
c:>hardping 192.168.1.1 
and it would reply with the mac or not.

I think they took it off their site, but you can still find it by googling "hardping freeware"

Answer (score 1):

How to Get an ARP Table with an IP Helper API
http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/i-n/internet/internetprotocolip/article.php/c6153

> GetIpNetTable: Retrieves address
>   resolution table information.
>
> SetIpNetEntry: Adds entry to the ARP
>   table.
>
> DeleteIpNetEntry: Deletes entry from
>   the ARP table.
>
> CreateIpNetEntry: Creates an entry in
>   the ARP table.
>
> FlushIpNetTable: Deletes all ARP
>   entries for the specified interface
>   from the ARP table
>
> SendARP: Sends an ARP request to
>   obtain the physical address that
>   corresponds to the specified
>   destination IP address.

Comment: link is broken - 404

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is not a built in tool to do this in Windows, there are some third party tools that will do this such as [Netscan](http://www.netscantools.com/nstpro_arpping.html), but its not free

Answer (score 0):

```
arp -a your.ip.here.jo
```

ex: `arp -a 192.168.0.1`

Comment: This command will only lookup against the current arp cache, not issue a new arp "Who has 192.168.0.1?" request